# useMatch() not working with React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I just updated my project to use `react-router-dom` v6 from v5 and the components that previously used `props.match` are no longer working using `useMatch`.

In Firefox I get the error - Can't access property "path", pattern is undefined

In Chrome I get the error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

The components look something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, useMatch, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { businessDetail } from "../../../../redux/actions/business";
import {
  BusinessSettingTeamButtons,
  BusinessSettingTeamBody
} from "./BusinessPageTeam";

function BusinessPage (props) {
  const params = useParams()
  const { url, pathname } = useMatch();

  const [slug, setSlug] = useState(params.businessSlug);

  // ADDED TO THE EDIT
  const businessSettingTeamButtons = <BusinessSettingTeamButtons
      url={url}
      setSettings={setSettings}/>

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadBusiness = () => {
      props.businessDetail(slug);
    }
    loadBusiness()
  }, [props.businessDetail])

  const bodies =
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={`${pathname}`}>
          {businessSettingProfileBody}
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${pathname}/team`}>
          {businessSettingTeamBody}
        </Route>
        <Route path={`${pathname}/settings`}>
          {businessSettingBody}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>

  return (
    <div>
      {bodies}
    </div>
  )
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    business: state.business,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { businessDetail })(BusinessPage);
```

`Routes` was previously named `Switch` and `pathname` was previously named `path`.

Child component:

```
export function BusinessSettingTeamButtons (props) {
  return (
    <nav>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-link"
        onClick={() => props.setSettings('profile')}
        to={`${props.url}`}
      >
        Profile
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-primary"
        onClick={() => props.setSettings('team')}
        to={`${props.url}/team`}
      >
        Team
      </Link>
      <Link
        className="btn btn-link"
        onClick={() => props.setSettings('settings')}
        to={`${props.url}/settings`}
      >
        Settings
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useMatch` hook takes a required path pattern for route matching.

See [`useMatch`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match)

> ```
> declare function useMatch<
>   ParamKey extends ParamParseKey<Path>,
>   Path extends string
> >(
>   pattern: PathPattern<Path> | Path // <-- required argument!
> ): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;
> ```

But the good news with `react-router-dom@6` is that you don't need to implement this part if all you are doing is rendering descendent routes. The `Routes` component builds descendent routes ***relative*** to the parent routes, so it's completely unnecessary to get the `url` and `pathname` of the parent route manually, you can just specify the relative paths.

The `Route` component also doesn't take children content, the only valid child of a `Route` component is another `Route` component in the case of nested routing. Place the routed content on the `Route` component's `element` prop, which takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX value. Be sure that `businessSettingProfileBody`, `businessSettingTeamBody`, and `businessSettingBody` are JSX values (*JSX literals are ok IIRC*). If they are not then this part of the UI might need to be tweaked a little.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Routes, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { businessDetail } from "../../../../redux/actions/business";

function BusinessPage () {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { businessSlug } = useParams();

  const business = useSelector(state => state.business); // where is this used?

  useEffect(() => {
    // dispatch on component mount/initial render
    dispatch(businessDetail(businessSlug));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={businessSettingProfileBody} />
        <Route path="/team" element={businessSettingTeamBody} />
        <Route path="/settings" element={businessSettingBody} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BusinessPage;
```

Comment: Thank you so much Drew! One more thing. I have child components with buttons that take in the url path from useMatch hook. When I try to remove the props.url it no longer takes me to the correct path (e.x. instead of site.com/businessname/team it just takes me to site.com/team which doesn't exist). I've edited the original post to show one of the child components

Comment: @SpaceFlightRelated These might also need relative target paths. Depending on where exactly the buttons are rendered in relation to the `BusinessPage` component rendered on `"/business"` the links probably just need a leading `"."` (*current path*) or `".."` (*back a path segment*). Something like `to="."` and `to="./team"`, or `to=".."` and `to="../team"`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Okay so that worked but now I am getting a 404 with "No routes matched location "/businessname/team". I don't think `<Route path="/team" element={businessSettingTeamBody} />`  is routing it to /businessname/team

Comment: @SpaceFlightRelated Ah, bummer. I think you're close. Relative links/routes can be tricky sometimes and I don't quite have the full UI/UX context. If it's not too much trouble do you think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this routing/UI code that we could inspect live?

Comment: Okay I created a very crude version here https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lake-ovyjt7 and am having the same issue. It seems to be a very simply issue with v6 that I am overlooking.

Comment: @SpaceFlightRelated `BusinessPage` is rendering descendent routes, so the root/parent route ***must*** also specify a trailing wildcard `"*"` matcher so that the descendent routes can also be matched and rendered, e.g. `{ path: "/business-page/*", element: <BusinessPage /> }`. [Forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usematch-not-working-with-react-router-v6-b5ryrn).